# Filter Nested array Python

Tags: python, arrays, nested

I have an output array like this after using "json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4"

```
{
    "totalCount": 8,
    "hasMore": false,
    "firstIndex": 0,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "7d5bb8asdfasdfasfdasdfasdfasdf",
            "name": "Corporate",
            "domainType": "AAAAAAAA",
            "description": "",
            "createdBy": "admin",
            "createDatetime": "2020/06/04 17:40:22",
            "parentDomainId": "8b208asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas",
            "zoneCount": 2,
            "subDomainCount": 1,
            "administratorCount": 0,
            "apCount": 0,
            "zeroTouchStatus": true
        },
```

Now when I try to filter it as follows
print(results['name']) or print(results['list'][0]['name'])

I keep getting this error message:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

This starts with a dict {}, then ther are lists [] of dict {} in here.  Based on that it should work.  Appreciate any guidance.  Thank you.

Comment: `json.dumps` returns *a string*. What you have above is a JSON string. Just don't serialize it into JSON

Answer (score 0):

It is clear by your data you posted that it is still in text format JSON. Convert to a python dict using `json.loads()`

```
result = json.loads(response.json())
print(results['name']) 
print(results['list'][0]['name'])
```

Comment: So when I try this.  I get an error still, "    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"

Comment: The code you put in your post CAN NOT be a python dict.  Since `true` and `false` would have had to been capitalized. Not to mention `json.dumps` creates a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `json.dumps(response.json())`. The return of this statement is a `str` so you cannot get items using [] notation. You can convert back it to a `dict`.

Comment: results = (json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))

print(results)
-------------------------
So after this convert it into dict and then filter you mean?